# How to share a list between two files

Tags: python

So I have two .py files that need to share a list, but I can't get it to work as it always creates a second list in place of using the first that was created.

Comment: Can you please show the code you have written so far, with the input and the expexted output?

Comment: @mvelay I tried to use a third file and use global variables, which didn't work as it created two list like I mentionned.

Comment: Post your code if you want to be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to import one of the .py files from the other. If the two .py files are running separately, then it is a lot harder to share a list between them. For example, if you have pscript1.py and pscript2.py:

pscript1.py

```
import pscript2

print sample_list
```

pscript2.py

```
sample_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If the programs are running separately, then you should implement some method of saving the list in a json file, and then reading/writing to the file from both programs. This is not very effecient, because you have to constantly open and close the file, but it will work. For more information on this, see:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html